# Importing an adjacency matrix in CSV (with labels) and drawing a graph (with labels)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have created an adjacency matrix in CSV with labels. Now I wish to import the matrix data and draw a network graph with labels at the nodes.

What code will do that?

Here is the same data:

```
,Bob,Jane,Steve,Joe
Bob,0,1,1,1
Jane,1,0,0,0
Steve,1,0,0,0
Joe,1,0,0,0
```

Comment: Please embed a _small_ sample CSV directly into the post. We prefer to keep questions self-contained so that readers can benefit from them even years later, when your Dropbox folder is gone. BTW your Dropbox folder is empty.

Comment: Dropbox says the directory is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that the input command results in:

```
in = Import["d:/tmp/tes.csv"]
(*{{"Bob", "Jane", "Steve", "Joe"}, {"Bob", 0, 1, 1, 1}, {"Jane", 1, 0, 
  0, 0}, {"Steve", 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"Joe", 1, 0, 0, 0}}*)
```

Then we can draw the graph:

```
neigh = in[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]];
AdjacencyGraph[in[[1]], neigh, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error here:
AdjacencyGraph::matsq: Argument neigh at position 2 is not a non-empty square matrix.

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault. I did not copy the line: `neigh = in[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]];` It is corrected now.